# 14.04 Mouse cursor disappears in lower half of the screen

Tags: cursor

This is a PC which has been switched off for a few months, so the first thing I did was update/upgrade apt and then reboot. I didn't notice the issue before doing this, but it *definitely* wasn't a problem prior to being switched off for those months.

The mouse cursor operates correctly over the whole screen area, and everything else appears on the screen as it should; but it is only displayed when in the top half. I appears to be a straight line right across, and happens even at the login screen (if I log out).

I tried a couple of solutions to what sounded similar provlems:
Post #10 here: https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/the-mysterious-case-of-disappearing-mouse-cursor-in-ubuntu-14-04-a-4175562392/
As well as installing gdm and selecting lightgdm.
Even after reboot there is no change.

What can I try to locate & fix this issue?

Comment: I don't know what caused this, but did you try to update the existing packages through Update Manager?  There might be an update for that issue. Also, what point release of Trusty do you have? 14.04/.1/.2/.3/.4/.5? I'm asking because there are some problems with 14.04.3.

Comment: This sometimes happens to my compter as well. I then have to open the settings for the monitor and correct the settings (mostly the refresh rate has reduced from 60Hz to 24Hz). Maybe the same thing happens to your settings.

Comment: I'm running 14.04.5 LTS, so doesn't seem to be that.

Comment: Refresh rate is 60.1, presumably the .1 is special for HDMI? I don't seem to be allowed to change it, though.

Comment: The graphical Update Manager fixed it somehow. I didn't realise that would update/change stuff which apt-get wouldn't.